# How to make a 2d map with perlin noise python

Tags: python, pyglet, terrain, perlin-noise

I have been experimenting on making a random map for a top down RPG I am making in Python. (and Pyglet) So far I have been making island by starting at 0,0 and going in a random direction 500 times (x+=32 or y -=32 sort of thing) However this doesn't look like a real image very much so I had a look at the Perlin Noise approach. How would I get a randomly generated map out of this :/ (preferably an island) and is it better than the random direction method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a perlin map can be generated easily.... it is simply a 2d array of values (typically 0 - 255) you just need to pick a threshold (say 126) anthing higher than that and render your land square.  otherwise render water

something like this may help
http://simblob.blogspot.com/2010/01/simple-map-generation.html

Comment: Found an awesome tutorial here also: http://breinygames.blogspot.co.nz/2012/06/generating-terrain-using-perlin-noise.html

Comment: Try this [polygon map generation](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/) also by Red Blob. It's quite remarkable and it's also generating islands.

Comment: Oh and there's more on gamedev: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/random-map-generation & http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18735/how-can-i-create-a-random-world-in-a-tile-engine?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use 1d perlin noise to calculate the radius from each point to the "center" of the island. It should be really easy to implement, but it will make more circular islands, and won't give each point different heights.